# RavenDB performance, 4-8s to load simple doc

Tags: ravendb

** UPDATED **
My RavenDB probably has a hundred or two hundred documents (it's a dev database).  Documents range from a few K to a few hundred K in size.
Upon loading of the home page, there is a major slowdown that occurs and I am not sure why.  Home controller will do a few simple calls to Raven, most to load things by Id.

**EDIT**: After much clean-up, I can see that the issue is not server-side related.  Fiddler shows that calls take no time at all to execute.  However, I believe that there is an issue with the way I'm using the Async capabilities of the session.

Here is an output from Ants Performance Profiler. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or can I provide any more information? 
Using ASP.NET/Autofac/Raven 2.* client

[image]

Here is what my Raven repository looks like (relevant part)

```
public class RavenAsyncRepository<TEntity> : IRavenAsyncRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly Func<IDocumentStore> _storeFactory;
    private readonly string _keyFormat;
    private IAsyncDocumentSession _session;

    public RavenAsyncRepository(Func<IDocumentStore> storeFactory)
    {
        _storeFactory = storeFactory;
        _keyFormat = typeof(TEntity).GetCustomAttribute<KeyFormatAttribute>().GetFormat();
    }

    private void EnsureOpenedSession()
    {
        if (_session != null) return;
        _session = _storeFactory().OpenAsyncSession();
        _session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
    }

    public async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetMany()
    {
        EnsureOpenedSession();
        return await _session.Query<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetSingle(string id)
    {
        EnsureOpenedSession();
        return await _session.LoadAsync<TEntity>(id);
    }
```

I belive the offending calls are:

```
        return await _identityRepository.GetSingle(n => n.UserName == userName);
```

and this

```
        var accounts = await _accountRepository.GetMany(n => n.UserProfiles.Any(u => u.IsEnabled && u.Name == user.UserName));
```

Comment: Can you show the Fiddler output? That would help narrow down what exactly is going on. Is the server remote?

Comment: @AyendeRahien thanks for your reply.  I've edited my question with further information and clarifications.  I'm surely doing something really stupid

Comment: Um, that isn't fiddler output. That is what we want to see